# Is there any L2TP client without IPsec?

Tags: nat, l2tp

I want to use L2TP to through NAT, but i do not need IPsec, because IPsec waste much CPU. I can setup one L2TP server on linux, so is there any L2TP windows client without IPsec ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use default L2TP windows client and [ProhibitIpSec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736542%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: And need reboot the Windows to make the change take effects.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that L2TP without IPsec in insecure.

"WARNING: Disabling IPSEC for L2TP connections is a severe limitation in security and is recommended only for troubleshooting." - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258261

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Rasman\Parameters
Add the following registry value to this key:

Value Name: ProhibitIpSec
Data Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1

Note that you must restart your Windows 2000-based computer for the changes to take effect.
```

Comment: If incapsulated protocol has it’s own encryption (and ppp does, it’s MPPE) then it’s as secure as the encryption is. So “l2tp without ipsec is unsecure” is generally an urban legend.